# How to unit test views in ember.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, model-view-controller, ember.js

We are in the process of learning Ember.js. We do all our development TDD, and want Ember.js to be no exception. We have experience building Backbone.js apps test-driven, so we are familiar with testing front-end code using Jasmine or Mocha/Chai.

When figuring out how to test views, we ran into a problem when the template for the view uses has a `#linkTo` statement. Unfortunately we are unable to find good test examples and practices. This gist is our quest to get answers how to decently unit-test ember applications.

When looking at the [test for linkTo in Ember.js source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember/tests/helpers/link_to_test.js), we noticed it contains a full wiring of an ember app to support `#linkTo`. Does this mean we cannot stub this behaviour when testing a template?

How do you create tests for ember views using template renders?

Here is [a gist](https://gist.github.com/matthijsgroen/4760701) with our test and a template that will make the test pass, and a template that will make it fail.

**view_spec.js.coffee**

```
# This test is made with Mocha / Chai,
# With the chai-jquery and chai-changes extensions

describe 'TodoItemsView', ->

  beforeEach ->
    testSerializer = DS.JSONSerializer.create
      primaryKey: -> 'id'

    TestAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend
      serializer: testSerializer
    TestStore = DS.Store.extend
      revision: 11
      adapter: TestAdapter.create()

    TodoItem = DS.Model.extend
      title: DS.attr('string')

    store = TestStore.create()
    @todoItem = store.createRecord TodoItem
      title: 'Do something'

    @controller = Em.ArrayController.create
      content: []

    @view = Em.View.create
      templateName: 'working_template'
      controller: @controller

    @controller.pushObject @todoItem

  afterEach ->
    @view.destroy()
    @controller.destroy()
    @todoItem.destroy()

  describe 'amount of todos', ->

    beforeEach ->
      # $('#konacha') is a div that gets cleaned between each test
      Em.run => @view.appendTo '#konacha'

    it 'is shown', ->
      $('#konacha .todos-count').should.have.text '1 things to do'

    it 'is livebound', ->
      expect(=> $('#konacha .todos-count').text()).to.change.from('1 things to do').to('2 things to do').when =>
        Em.run =>
          extraTodoItem = store.createRecord TodoItem,
            title: 'Moar todo'
          @controller.pushObject extraTodoItem
```

**broken_template.handlebars**

```
<div class="todos-count"><span class="todos">{{length}}</span> things to do</div>

{{#linkTo "index"}}Home{{/linkTo}}
```

**working_template.handlebars**

```
<div class="todos-count"><span class="todos">{{length}}</span> things to do</div>
```

Comment: Basically you'll have trouble instantiating stuff in isolation. Ember wants your entire app running. This is not an answer, but in general I prefer integration tests (see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heK78M6Ql9Q)) over unit tests. I've seen people try to test views in isolation, and even when it works it doesn't seem like a good strategy. See http://www.slideshare.net/jo_liss/testing-ember-apps/27 for some of the rationales behind that.

Answer (score 9):

Our solution has been to essentially load the whole application, but isolate our test subjects as much as possible. For example,

```
describe('FooView', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.foo = Ember.Object.create();
    this.subject = App.FooView.create({ foo: this.foo });
    this.subject.append();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    this.subject && this.subject.remove();
  });

  it("renders the foo's favoriteFood", function() {
    this.foo.set('favoriteFood', 'ramen');
    Em.run.sync();
    expect( this.subject.$().text() ).toMatch( /ramen/ );
  });
});
```

That is, the router and other globals are available, so it's not *complete* isolation, but we can easily send in doubles for things closer to the object under test.

If you really want to isolate the router, the `linkTo` helper looks it up as `controller.router`, so you could do

```
this.router = {
  generate: jasmine.createSpy(...)
};

this.subject = App.FooView.create({
  controller: { router: this.router },
  foo: this.foo
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can handle this is to create a stub for the linkTo helper and then use it in a before block.  That will bypass all the extra requirements of the real linkTo (e.g. routing) and let you focus on the contents of the view.  Here's how I'm doing it:

```
// Test helpers
TEST.stubLinkToHelper = function() {
    if (!TEST.originalLinkToHelper) {
        TEST.originalLinkToHelper = Ember.Handlebars.helpers['link-to'];
    }
    Ember.Handlebars.helpers['link-to'] = function(route) {
        var options = [].slice.call(arguments, -1)[0];
        return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, Em.View.extend({
            tagName: 'a',
            attributeBindings: ['href'],
            href: route
        }), options);
    };
};

TEST.restoreLinkToHelper = function() {
    Ember.Handlebars.helpers['link-to'] = TEST.originalLinkToHelper;
    TEST.originalLinkToHelper = null;
};

// Foo test
describe('FooView', function() {
    before(function() {
        TEST.stubLinkToHelper();
    });

    after(function() {
        TEST.restoreLinkToHelper();
    });

    it('renders the favoriteFood', function() {
        var view = App.FooView.create({
            context: {
                foo: {
                    favoriteFood: 'ramen'
                }
            }
        });

        Em.run(function() {
            view.createElement();
        });

        expect(view.$().text()).to.contain('ramen');
    });
});
```