# Ember Unit Testing Templates

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, qunit

I'm in the early stages of using Ember in a project. So far I'm very excited about the possibilities it opens up!

We're writing integration tests as described in [their docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/integration/). We also plan to do unit testing of various things at a later stage when required (components, controllers, views etc).

Right now, however, we just have a basic template to which a model is bound. For illustrative purposes it could simply be:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

We're precompiling our templates on the server: they're available in the `Ember.TEMPLATES` collection.

We'd like to unit test just this template with a model (created in the test) bound to it. My thinking is that we should just be able to load the app on a page, specify a page element into which the template should be rendered, create a dummy model, bind it 'somehow' to the template, render the template and then do some jQuery assertions. Sounds straight-forward, but I can't seem to find out how to do this in an easy way.

I've already looked at [this post](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/04/09/Unit-testing-your-emberjs-templates-with-jasmine-part-2/) and posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903273/how-to-unit-test-views-in-ember-js), but they either seem to be out of date or deal with views, which I don't think we have a need for with such a simple template.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Am I looking at this problem the wrong way? We're using qunit and ember-qunit combi as recommended in the Ember docs, in case that's of importance.

Comment: This seems more like an integration test than a unit test, meaning it'd be easier to test during integration testing.

Comment: +1 to integration testing for this scenario. If you need to test a "hbs helper" or something more isolated (like a controller function/view function) I'd say unit test it but the value-add here is that a model and template work together like you'd expect and a true integration test solves this best IMHO

Comment: Thank you both so much for your contributions. Really appreciate it! #ember4lyf ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always create a view on the fly and attach a controller and your template to it, then attach it to the page and test that the bindings are working.

```
var controller = Em.ObjectController.create({
  model: { title: 'hello'}
});
var fooView = Em.View.create({
  container: App.__container__,
  templateName: 'foo',
  controller: controller
});

// start up the run loop and inject template into the page
Em.run(function(){
  fooView.appendTo('#foo');  
});

equal(find("h1").length, 1, "h1 is injected");
equal(find("h1").html(), 'hello', "text says hello");
fooView.remove(); // cleanup
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wipo/45/edit

Comment: That looks like a very helpful answer, thank you. I'll try it out and mark your answer as correct if it does the job.